# how to set classpath of  log4j.properties in jboss6

Tags: java, apache-axis, jboss6.x

Hello friend I have deployed `axis2.war` in jboss6final, I have some problem in `axis2.war`.

`axis2.war` directory structure is `axis2.war/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties` which shows log4j.properties is present in war.

My question is how to set log4j.properties in Classpath. Because when I try to deploy axis2.war in jboss it will give some error like

```
012-05-30 16:33:53,867 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.cdac.AsyncResponseComponent.PrepareSubmitResponse).

2012-05-30 16:33:53,867 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

2012-05-30 16:33:53,868 ERROR [STDERR] (http-127.0.0.1-7001-1) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

if any one have some valuable time so please help me thanks.....

**log4j.properties**

```
#

# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one

# or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file

# distributed with this work for additional information

# regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file

# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the

# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance

# with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at

#

# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

#

# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,

# software distributed under the License is distributed on an

# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY

# KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the

# specific language governing permissions and limitations

# under the License.

#



# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.

log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE

#log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE



# Set the enterprise logger priority to FATAL

log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL

log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL

log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=FATAL

log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=FATAL



# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n



# LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.

log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=axis2.log

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: The location of your log4j.properties is correct, it is in the application classpath. Can you post its content? Do you have log4j jar in `axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: yes my log4j.jar is correct place (axis2.war/WEB-INF/lib). what do you want to post please say i post immediately.....

Comment: Can you post the log4j.properties?

Comment: i post log4j.properties please check it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specifically set log4j.properties in Classpath. Just place the properties file into the project at the root level automatically adds it into the project's classpath.

Comment: Then have your specified
<context-param>
<param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param> 
in web.xml file

Comment: under the axis2/WEB-INF/web.xml no context parameter will be there. can i add <context-param> <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name> <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value> </context-param> directly in web.xml